# Distribute N balls into M bins

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

**Problem 1 :-**
There are N bins and M balls. Each Ball have a score. Problem is to distribute M balls into N bins such that - 
 1. Average score of balls in Bin 1 = Average score of balls in bin 2 and so on.
 2. Balls should be distributed into bins with ratio - A:B:C... A,B,C is provided.

Note: Since a solution may not always be possible, it is fine to have some deviation in both goals.

For example - Distribute 1000 balls into 4 bins such that 1) Bin 1 have 10% balls 2) Bin 2 have 30% balls 3) Bin 3 have 40% balls and 4) Bin 4 have 20% balls + also maintain same average score constraint.

**Problem 2 :-** Same as problem 1 except now Total number of balls in not known upfront and we need to distribute the balls as and when they are recieved maintaining the same constraints and achieving same goal.

Comment: Are the scores any real numbers or are they integers?

Comment: Score is between 0.100 to 1.000 with 3 degree of precision

Comment: It is equivalent to integer scores from 100 to 1000000.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out distributing N balls to M bins randomly is good enough. I am able to maintain the distribution ration required and yet have average score across all bins almost same.